# boto's Glacier-to-S3 restore() function not working

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-glacier

I'm fairly new to both python and the S3/Glacier integration interface that `boto` provides.  However, I have discovered several flaws that seem to be particularly undocumented/unsolved, flaws that are seriously hindering my progress on my current work project.

My recent dilemma pertains to the `restore()` function within the `boto` library.  Quite simply, it's not working at all.  I had a suspicion for some time that the problem was related to an issue with the `Key` object's inconsistency of keeping track of `storage_class`'s of data stored in S3 buckets.  This page can be a resource as to some of the specifics of that problem: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1173

To elaborate on the `Key` consistency issue, consider the following scenario concerning an object that has already been archived to Glacier from S3:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
...
conn = S3Connection(access_key_id, secret_key)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
key_object = Key(bucket)

print bucket.get_key(filename).storage_class
...
key_object.key = filename
for item in bucket.list():
    if item.key == filename:
        break

print item.storage_class
```

A couple clarifications.  I understand that the `for` loop that searches the bucket for a key is wildly inefficient, however that is precisely the mystery.

The first `print` statement will yield: `u'STANDARD'`

The second: `u'GLACIER'`

Moving forward now, I believe this inconsistency is affecting the efficacy of the `restore()` operation.  If I attempt to `key.restore(days=num_days)` on either 'key' derivations I listed above, neither of them indicates that it had any affect in restoring objects from Glacier back to standard S3 accessibility.  Furthermore, an attempt to `restore` returns `None`.  At this point, I'm at a complete loss as to what could possibly explain this malfunction.  Is it something programmatically wrong on my part?  Or is there something innately broken about `boto`?

Any assistance you could provide me with would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

NOTE: I did not forget basic error checking i.e. does the file exist in the bucket? has the file already been restored? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what my confusion was.  Once an object is on Glacier, it remains on Glacier.  It *can* be restored such that it can be downloaded, but its storage class will never change from Glacier back to S3 standard (to do that you must make a copy of the object and ensure that the copy is in standard storage).

The Key inconsistency remains an issue, but I've found some hack ways around it (which I would preferably avoid but, for now, I have no choice).

Comment: I know this is a year later, but can you share your hack that you used?  I'm struggling with this same issue.

Comment: I know this is a year later too, but I'm pretty sure I just created a function using the code from my question: iterating through bucket.list(), breaking on a match between an item's key and the target filename, and then returning `str(item.storage_class)`. I wrote this during my first internship and from what I understand it's still being used and no one has had any complaints about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already keeping track of the filenames, have you tried following the doc's example via http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html#transitioning-objects-to-glacier

```
conn = S3Connection(access_key_id, secret_key)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
key = bucket.get_key(filename)
key.restore(days=5)
```

use key.ongoing_restore to get the restore status

Comment: Yes I have tried producing a proper Key object by using get_key(), and while it does return a Key that is apparently associated with the target Glacier object, it returns 'STANDARD' as opposed to 'GLACIER' when I invoke ongoing_restore().  The for loop in my original question demonstrates the inconsistency of bucket methods as they retrieve Key objects, which of course could be part of the hidden problem in this madness.
What confuses me is restoring should be a fundamental, fully-functioning capability of boto, seeing as once you archive with boto, you can only retrieve with boto.